# MS Access vba query with Format date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to create a query to Count items and having three WHERE conditions but there is no result when I run the code, not even an error one. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qryMajorDesignReview As String
Dim tblMainReportLOI As String


qryMajorDesignReview = "SELECT Count(tblLOI.loiActivities) As MajorDesignReview, INTO tblMainReportLOI FROM tblLOI " & _
                   "WHERE tblLOI.loiActivities='PSG Major design review for new or existing facilities' " & _
                   "AND Format([loiDate], ""yyyy"")=[Forms]![frmMonthlyDivisionReports]![txtYear] " & _
                   "AND Format([loiDate], ""mmmm"")=[Forms]![frmMonthlyDivisionReports]![txtMonth]; "

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblMainReportLOI"

Err.Clear

CurrentDb.Execute qryMajorDesignReview
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
strError = Err.Description
End If

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma before INTO. Also, concatenate variables. References to form controls are variables. Can use apostrophe instead of doubled quotes in Format(). Could use Year() function instead of Format.

```
qryMajorDesignReview = "SELECT Count(tblLOI.loiActivities) As MajorDesignReview INTO tblMainReportLOI FROM tblLOI " & _
                   "WHERE tblLOI.loiActivities='PSG Major design review for new or existing facilities' " & _
                   "AND Year([loiDate])=" & [Forms]![frmMonthlyDivisionReports]![txtYear] & _
                   " AND Format([loiDate], 'mmmm')='" & [Forms]![frmMonthlyDivisionReports]![txtMonth] & "'"
```

Comment: The text versions of the month, mmmm, also need to be quoted.

Comment: Did that, I still have no results, the table is not created when I run the code. The form with data controls is open

Comment: It works fine without Format but I need those conditions for the query, the year and the month from the Form

Comment: Sorry, missed that the month Format was for the full name. Edited answer.